# Tool to create the icons for an Android app

Tags: icon, software-recommendation

I am an Android developer. Currently I am working on an Android app where I need to to create the icons even though I don't know of any tool to create the icons.

Is there good websites which can help to get the all types of icons and use them, and any best tool to create icons then generate according to screen density?

Comment: Use Illustrator/Inkscape to create icons - Also you can download the Android icon packs [here](https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html)

Comment: Hello user19345, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. As-is, your question is way to broad for our Q&A format. On icon design, one could write a book, and then some. If you're stuck at a certain point in the process, show us what you've got and we'll be happy to help you. Thanks for your understanding. Don't be discouraged, we are aware that using this site can be a learning curve. We *are* happy to have you!

Comment: @SaturnsEye I heard about the photoshop also. Isn't that good ?? or Illustrator is much better than that ?

Comment: @Vincent Can you suggest any website where I can find generic icons of real world not specific to android

Comment: Photoshop is best for finalising; you'll be better off creating the icons initially in Illustrator.

As for icon packs. Just search google, there's thousands out there.

Comment: @SaturnsEye Yes I searched I found iconfinder but probably you may know better than this

Comment: which android versions are you planning on supporting?

Comment: @KumarHarsh Android 4.0 +

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking to design your own icons, I'd recommend you go with SVG icons (Android 3.0+). I hope you are not supporting 2.3.

Anyways, having SVG icons is better than an icon font. [Read here](http://ianfeather.co.uk/ten-reasons-we-switched-from-an-icon-font-to-svg/)

To design SVG icons, use Illustrator. It is used for Vector designs. Photoshop is used for Raster designs (if you scale rasters to bigger size, they will start tearing or pixellating)

I'd recommend you use Illustrator, design each icon in one "artboard", and when done, Save the whole icon-set into different SVG files. Then use [this tool](https://github.com/filamentgroup/grunticon) to do all the icon generation, which you can then directly include in your html.

---

On the other hand, if you are OK with pre-existing icon-sets, look at [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) or [Glyphicons](http://glyphicons.com/) or [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io/)